# Opencv 3.3.1 installation [7%] Compilation terminated

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspbian, stretch

I am getting Error when i run `make`

```
Scanning dependencies of target carotene_objs
[  7%] Building CXX object 3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/src/absdiff.cpp.o
/home/pi/opencv-3.3.1/3rdparty/carotene/src/absdiff.cpp:42:22: fatal error: common.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "common.hpp"
                      ^

compilation terminated.
3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target '3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/src/absdiff.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/src/absdiff.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:547: recipe for target '3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My configuration

```
Cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.3.1/modules \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
```

I just want it for python 3
Am following these steps https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/
What could be the problem? Am running a fresh copy of Raspbian stretch noobs on pi model B... Thanks

Comment: Can any body help me please

Comment: Try using `$HOME` in place of `~` maybe.

Comment: @MarkSetchell
No it wasn't the problem...what i see is a problem with absdiff.cpp idk what is it